# memmap boot parameters not getting set correctly

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2

I am trying to reserve memory using `memmap` boot parameters by following these steps:

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv set memmap_val0='1023M\$1M'
   sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv set memmap_val1='2G\$4G'
   ```
2. Verify the settings:

   ```
   $ sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv list
   memmap_val0=1023M\$1M
   memmap_val1=2G\$4G
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/default/grub`, and add the following:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="memmap=\$memmap_val0 memmap=\$memmap_val1 quiet splash"
   ```
4. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. I check the `/boot/grub/grubenv` and see that it adds two "backslash characaters":

   ```
   memmap_val0=1023M\\$1M
   memmap_val1=2G\\$4G
   ```
6. After rebooting, I check:

   ```
   $ cat /proc/cmdline 
   BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-67-generic root=UUID=9e28b9d1-5270-439a-8c05-d0d55ee62b71 ro memmap= memmap= quiet splash
   ```

`memmap` boot parameters are not getting set. Any suggestion on this please?